# What is the most efficient way to use mesh grid with parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

```
def s(x,y,z,t1,t2):
    return x + y + z + t1 + t2
        
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6]
Z = [7,8,9]
Theta = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,1)]
```

Is there any way for me to efficiently construct an array containing the evaluations of X cross Y cross Z cross Theta with respect to the function s ? Note that I do not want s(1,4,7,1,3), but I do want s(1,4,7,1,2); as in, I don't want s to be evaluated at X cross Y cross Z cross {1,3,5,1} cross {2,4,6,1}.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want a `numpy` answer, define the inputs as arrays, not lists.  And tell us the expected `shape` of the result.

Comment: `t1, t2 = zip(*Theta)` may split `Theta` into 2 lists that conform to the `s` input.  You still have the issue of mixing 3 len 3 lists, and 2 length 4.

Comment: Where's your attempt to use 'mesh grid' (efficient or not)?

Answer (score 1):

```
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6]
Z = [7,8,9]
Theta = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,1)]

[(a,b,c,d) for a,b,c,d in zip(X,Y,Z,Theta)]

#[(1, 4, 7, (1, 2)), (2, 5, 8, (3, 4)), (3, 6, 9, (5, 6))]
```

Or

```
[(a,b,c,*d) for a,b,c,d in zip(X,Y,Z,Theta)]
#[(1, 4, 7, 1, 2), (2, 5, 8, 3, 4), (3, 6, 9, 5, 6)]
```

If you want sum:

```
[sum([a,b,c,*d]) for a,b,c,d in zip(X,Y,Z,Theta)]
#[15, 22, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
results = [s(x, y, z, t1, t2) for x in X
                              for y in Y
                              for z in Z
                              for t1, t2 in Theta]
```

is the most efficient pure python way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your lists:

```
In [2]: X = [1,2,3]
   ...: Y = [4,5,6]
   ...: Z = [7,8,9]
   ...: Theta = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(1,1)]
```

It looks like you should split `Theta` into two lists, as with:

```
In [5]: T1,T2 = zip(*Theta)
In [6]: T1,T2
Out[6]: ((1, 3, 5, 1), (2, 4, 6, 1))
```

A flat zip:

```
In [7]: list(zip(X,Y,Z,T1,T2))
Out[7]: [(1, 4, 7, 1, 2), (2, 5, 8, 3, 4), (3, 6, 9, 5, 6)]
```

But to get every combination:

```
In [8]: [(x,y,z,t1,t2) for x in X for y in Y for z in Z for t1 in T1 for t2 in T2]
Out[8]: 
[(1, 4, 7, 1, 2),
 (1, 4, 7, 1, 4),
 (1, 4, 7, 1, 6),
 (1, 4, 7, 1, 1),
 (1, 4, 7, 3, 2),
 (1, 4, 7, 3, 4),
 ...
 ]
```

For a total of:

```
In [9]: len(_)
Out[9]: 432
```

And you could easily pass those to your function or just use `sum()`.

But you mention `mesh grid` and tag `numpy`, so using that:

Passing these lists to `meshgrid`:

```
In [10]: Xa,Ya,Za,T1a,T2a = np.meshgrid(X,Y,Z,T1,T2, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
```

That makes 5 arrays, with shapes like:

```
In [11]: Xa.shape
Out[11]: (3, 1, 1, 1, 1)    
In [12]: T1a.shape
Out[12]: (1, 1, 1, 4, 1)
```

If I didn't specify `sparse`, the meshgrid arrays would all have shape as `res` below.

```
In [14]: def s(x,y,z,t1,t2):
    ...:     return x + y + z + t1 + t2
    ...:     

In [15]: res = s(Xa,Ya,Za,T1a,T2a)    
In [16]: res.shape
Out[16]: (3, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

That's same number of combinations as with the lists, but arranged as 5d array:

```
In [17]: res.size
Out[17]: 432
```

A sample 2d array:

```
In [19]: res[0,0,0]
Out[19]: 
array([[15, 17, 19, 14],
       [17, 19, 21, 16],
       [19, 21, 23, 18],
       [15, 17, 19, 14]])
```

If I made an array from `Theta`, I could have gotten the `T1,T2` values by selecting columns:

```
In [20]: ThetaA = np.array(Theta)
In [21]: ThetaA
Out[21]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 1]])
In [23]: ThetaA[:,0], T1
Out[23]: (array([1, 3, 5, 1]), (1, 3, 5, 1))
```

Read up on `broadcasting` to learn how the 'sparse' `Xa`, `Ya`, etc arrays work together to create the 5d `res` array.